# UIImagePicker delegate doesn't get called

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I have two buttons: one for taking photo and one for choosing it from the photo library. They both call UIImagePickerDelegate. The problem is that UIImagePickerDelegate gets called after choosing photo from the library, but it doesn't get called after taking a picture. So when I take a picture and press "Use", I get back to my view, but nothing happens. Here is my code:

```
open class BackgroundImageViewController: UIViewController, BackgroundViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

  var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

    @IBAction func didTapTakePhoto(_ sender: UIButton) {
        imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        // This part works fine, view for taking picture is presented, and I can take a picture successfully.
    }
    
    @IBAction func didTapChoosePhoto(_ sender: UIButton) {
        imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}

extension BackgroundImageViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
    
    public func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        // This method is getting called only when I choose the photo from the library, not when I take the picture. 
        let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as! UIImage
        imageView.image = image
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    public func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
}
```

This problem is driving me mad, because code for two buttons is almost identical. For sure, I have all necessary permissions set in my `info.plist` file:

[image]

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Maybe you accidentally denied permissions in your app to access camera. Try removing your app from the device before building & running it in XCode.

Comment: I've already done it, it doesn't help. Plus I've mentioned that I can take a picture, I just can't use it, because delegate doesn't get called.

Comment: The same code worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from ios 14 it's recommended to use PHPickerViewController

```
@available(iOS 14, *)
extension YourViewController : PHPickerViewControllerDelegate {
    public func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        guard !results.isEmpty else { return }
        
        if imageResult.itemProvider.canLoadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) {
            imageResult.itemProvider.loadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) { (selectedImage, error) in
                //Selected Image is what you need
            }}
    }
    
    func openGaleryPHPicker(){
        
        //let library = PHPhotoLibrary.shared()
        var config = PHPickerConfiguration(photoLibrary: .shared())
        config.selectionLimit = 1
        config.filter = PHPickerFilter.images
        config.preferredAssetRepresentationMode = .automatic
        
        let pickerViewController = PHPickerViewController(configuration: config)
        pickerViewController.delegate = self
        
        present(pickerViewController, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Also for request Authorization it should be written

```
if #available(iOS 14, *) {

PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization(for: .readWrite) { status in
    switch status {
    case .notDetermined:
        // The user hasn't determined this app's access.
        PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization(for: .readWrite) {
            status in
            switch status  {
            case .authorized:
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.openGaleryPHPicker(isLimited: false)
                }
            case .limited:
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.openGaleryPHPicker(isLimited: true)
                }
            case .notDetermined:
                break
            case .denied, .restricted:
                self.requestToOpenSettings()
            }
        }
    case .restricted, .denied:
        self.requestToOpenSettings()
        // The system restricted this app's access.
        // The user explicitly denied this app's access.
    case .authorized:
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.openGaleryPHPicker(isLimited: false)
        }
    case .limited:
        // The user authorized this app to access Photos data.
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.openGaleryPHPicker(isLimited: true)
        }
        
        // The user authorized this app for limited Photos access.
    @unknown default:
        fatalError()
    }
}
}
```